# Google map Implementation in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-maps

I already implemented google mapping functionality in my iphone application.It works fine but if the location to search is wrong string then it maps a location and it redirects to current location only after the search button clicks. How to implement that if the location is wrong then directly go to the current location? My code is like below

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?z=14&q=%@",message] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];        
}
```

please give me a solution as soon as possible 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You must be loading the URL in the webview. You can perform checks using the javascript and accordingly redirect to the current location in case there is any problem with the string entered. You can also check for the implementation here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/tutorial-iphone

Comment: You could try a HTTP HEAD request (NSURLRequest) and check the status code (i.e. == 200)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you lose control the moment you leave your app, you should always perform the validity check **before** opening the URL by passing `message` to a CLGeocoder or a 3rd party Geocoder .

[CLGeocoder Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Basically query for the location string inside your app, **then** format your url accordingly.